# How to predict a missing score?

Tags: prediction, missing-data

Assume you have the scores of the first, second, and final exam for a group of students. Suppose a student miss the first and/or second exam.
What are the most appropriate statistics approaches that can be used to predict the missing score?

Comment: What assumption are you making about where this student might score?

Comment: No assumptions assumed

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous ways do deal with the missing values, which is called [*Imputation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imputation_(statistics)). Common approaches include:

- Use the mean grade for the exam
- Use the grade of the nearest (gradewise most similar) other student (or a mean of $k$ nearest students)

In the second case you have to somehow deal with computing their similarity with missing values. Without further details it is not really possible to say what is the most appropriate way for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Estimate the joint distribution of Score 1, Score 2 and Score 3. If you have many observations (1000+) , you can try to estimate the distribution nonparametrically (using the joint empirical cdf, for example). In the cases of smaller sample size, you would have to postulate a parametric family, like multivariate normal, multivariate Student, etc. You can estimate the model using *full information maximum  likelihood* and then calculate the prediction of a given score as its conditional expectation given the other  scores.